# Convert xs:string to java.util.UUID in jaxb

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, uuid

In jaxb, how do you convert a string in xsd to java.util.UUID? Is there a built-in data type converter or do I have to create my own custom converter?

Comment: Have a look at [Blaise Doughan post about XML adapters](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html).

Comment: Apparently there's no default converter and I have to create my own. What I did was pretty much the same as the provided answers below. I had an existing bindings.xjb so it was a bit easier just modifying it.  The node xpath thing had issues on multiple nodes but that's another story :) Thanks guys. I'll choose @mwsltn for his effort.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is **much** easier to do if you start with Java classes and use JAXB annotations. However, to do this using schema you must use a custom bindings file. Here is an example:

Schema: (example.xsd)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://www.example.com"
           xmlns="http://www.example.com"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:simpleType name="uuid-type">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value=".*"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:complexType name="example-type">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="uuid" type="uuid-type"/>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="example" type="example-type"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Bindings: (bindings.xjb) (Note that for brevity in `printMethod` and `parseMethod` I assumed that the `UuidConverter` class was in the default package. These should be fully qualified in reality. So if `UuidConverter` where in package `com.foo.bar` then the values should be like `com.foo.bar.UuidConverter.parse` and `com.foo.bar.UuidConverter.print`

```
<!-- Modify the schema location to be a path or url -->
<jxb:bindings version="1.0"
              xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              node="/xs:schema"
              schemaLocation="example.xsd">
    <!-- Modify this XPATH to suit your needs! -->
    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='uuid-type']">
        <jxb:javaType name=" java.util.UUID"
                      parseMethod="UuidConverter.parse"
                      printMethod="UuidConverter.print"/>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

UuidConverter.java:

```
import java.util.UUID;

public class UuidConverter {
    public static UUID parse(String xmlValue) {
        return UUID.fromString(xmlValue);
    }

    public static String print(UUID value) {
        return value.toString();
    }
}
```

Sadly I can't point you to a good reference because its really not documented well. There are bits and pieces of how it all works spread out in blog posts. Took me a few hours to make this work the first time. :-/

Comment: UuidConverter can be omitted 
`<jxb:javaType name="java.util.UUID"
    parseMethod="UUID.fromString"
    printMethod="java.util.Objects.toString" />`

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple converter yourself:

```
UUID.fromString(String uuid);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html