# Custom parse & print methods for WSDLs with several schemas

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, wsdl, schema

I have problems using custom javaTypes for WSDL's where there are several schemas. The bindings works for the schemas with the given namespace, but the compilation fails for the schemas without the namespace.

this is the bindings.xml file:

```
<jaxb:bindings version="2.1" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
           xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:common="urn:my:ns">
<jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false">
    <jaxb:serializable uid="1"/>
    <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:date"
                   parseMethod="org.apache.cxf.xjc.runtime.DataTypeAdapter.parseDate"
                   printMethod="org.apache.cxf.xjc.runtime.DataTypeAdapter.printDate"/>
    <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.Calendar" xmlType="xs:dateTime"
                   parseMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime"
                   printMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDateTime"/>
    <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.UUID" xmlType="common:uuid"
                   parseMethod="my.package.UuidConverter.parse"
                   printMethod="my.package.UuidConverter.print"/>
</jaxb:globalBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

I am using cxf-codegen-plugin

the error message is: *undefined simple type*

**Is it possible to ignore the UUID binding when urn:my:ns is not present in one of the schemas? or is it possible to archive this binding using a different method?**

Comment: Are you sure that you are not missing a binding for another simple type on which the failing schemas depend?  In other words, they may not depend on `common:uuid`, but might they depend on another simple type that you have missed?

Comment: @J0e3gan No, I don't think so, and I verified by turning the custom parser/printer on and off.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe it is possible to conditionally ignore the `UUID` binding like you describe; and I am not sure I follow what you mean by asking whether it is "possible to archive this binding", but I sense it is not too.

`UUID` typically converts to `xs:string` as [discussed in the Java forums](https://www.java.net//node/644490).  [JAX-B documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnazq.html) confirms this mapping too.  (Just search for *UUID* in the linked documentation page.)

Consider something like this instead:

```
<jaxb:bindings version="2.1" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
           xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false">
    <jaxb:serializable uid="1"/>
    <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:date"
                   parseMethod="org.apache.cxf.xjc.runtime.DataTypeAdapter.parseDate"
                   printMethod="org.apache.cxf.xjc.runtime.DataTypeAdapter.printDate"/>
    <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.Calendar" xmlType="xs:dateTime"
                   parseMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime"
                   printMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDateTime"/>
    <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.UUID" xmlType="xs:string"
                   parseMethod="my.package.UuidConverter.parse"
                   printMethod="my.package.UuidConverter.print"/>
</jaxb:globalBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

If you still have problems, consider this [related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565158/convert-xsstring-to-java-util-uuid-in-jaxb).

Comment: I don't think that will work as I would like it to, the reason for that is that your example will parse all instances of {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string, what I want is to make a parser for {urn:my:ns}uuid. My original example works just fine if use it on a single schema with {urn:my:ns}uuid present.

Comment: @Vegard, thanks for clarifying.  Sorry that I could not help with something more specific.

Comment: Thanks for this. Also works for me with joda class `DateTime`